# Why did Ben manipulate Locke into not entering the code?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost

In Season 2, Ben (as fake Henry Gale) was trying to manipulate Locke into not entering the code into the computer in the Swan Station. This was made clear in particular when Ben told Locke that never entered the code.

**Why did Ben wanted Locke not to enter the code?**

I think, Ben wanted Locke to pick a fight with Jack (and maybe others like Eko). But Ben should be aware of the consequences of not entering the code (It is likely that at least Richard is aware of the consequences as after the incident, the others and the Dharma initiative have been cooperating when building the Swan Station. Then Ben should know of it as well - especially since he knew of the existence of the Swan Station before being kidnapped). So at least for Ben's own security, he should not risk the case that the code is not being entered.

Even if he didn't know, he must know that the Dharma people did this for decades and should at least be afraid of the possible unknown consequences?

Comment: I don't remember the show well enough to tackle an answer, but there are a lot of theories about this [raging on the Lost Wikipedia](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Lockdown_incident/Theories). You should maybe check them out and consider writing your own answer up if no answer is forthcoming.

Comment: I cant recall Ben ever telling Locke not to enter the code. Which episode was this? Lockdown?

Comment: Ben claims he didn't push the button, during the Lockdown, when he climbed through the ducts to the control room, and that nothing happened. This was, most likely, a lie, and doesn't seem to serve any other purpose than to convince Locke the button does nothing, i.e. there's no point in pressing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Ben wanted to mess with Locke's head and cause contention. This is the first way in which he manipulates Locke through lies and misinformation and it becomes the common thread in their relationship.
2. Ben would have also known about The Pearl station which was where Locke learned about the observation experiment. Ben could very likely have known about this "experiment" as well and been duped into thinking it was all a hoax.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ben wanted Locke to not enter the numbers so that the hatch would eventually explode rendering the island incapable of communication. Ben did not want anyone else leaving the island.  However if Ben did not enter the numbers at that time that he did, then he would lose trust he was trying to build or he would have gotten hurt in the explosion.

Comment: Saying, "I think," makes this more of a comment than an answer. Could you flesh things out a bit more?

Comment: Not entering the code doesn't explodes the hatch but might have attracted some plane of ship.